# How to get rid of YSOD but keep the standard logging functionality?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

The default options of `<system.web><customErrors>` don't work very well in an ASP.NET MVC app if you want to return the actual HTTP status codes like 404, 500 etc. instead of 302 (because it works only with Web Forms).

No matter where and how I catch exceptions (like in Global.asax or in a global error handler) and "swallow" the exception (e. g. using `Server.ClearError()`), I have full control of what is rendered to the client but I loose the default logging (Web Events written to the Windows Event Log). This kind of logging works fine for me, it's very robust and I have Event Log monitoring anyway, so that's exactly what I want for logging.

Is there anything I can do to e. g. in Global.asax to simply force ASP.NET to log the current error as a Web Event and *then* clear the error?

A solution that requires ASP.NET 4 and IIS7.5 Integrated Mode would be fine.

One option that kind of works would be the use of `<system.webServer><httpErrors>`, however this works only with `existingResponse="Replace"`, not `Auto`, because ASP.NET seems to automatically set `TrySkipIisCustomErrors=true`, and I would need this on `Auto` since a few controllers of my application need to return custom error pages (XML).

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You could always log to the event log yourself when catching the error in a global error handler. I'll check, but I'm pretty sure this is what we settled for. Older version of IIS, though.

Comment: There are also 3rd party error loggers that might make this a lot easier for you as well (ELMAH, Log4Net).

Comment: @dash, I'm aware of that, however the event log messages generated by default are pretty sophisticated (with lots of data depending on the context), actually I don't like the idea to reinvent the wheel here...

Comment: @Tommy, thanks for your suggestion, however I like the logging as it is out-of-the-box (e. g. ELMAH can't even log to the Windows Event Log!), I just want to decouple it from the YSOD.